# Creating preview image/thumbnail of url in Node/Express

Tags: node.js, express

I'm wondering if anyone had experience creating a thumbnail-like preview of pdfs without saving images in a db. I'm storing url links to music pdfs and am trying to create a small preview of the pages so that clients can see some of the first page of the music in advance. I'm looking to see if it's possible without saving images of the page in the db and instead generate the preview on the page load.

Comment: This package? https://www.npmjs.com/package/pdf-thumbnail pdf-thumbnail creates a thumbnail of the first page of a pdf file. You can also manipulate the image

Comment: I was taking a look at that and it looks like it has some pc software dependencies; trying to find a software-less solution. Thanks though!